# MYSQL updating multiple tables error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, syntax-error

I am trying to update a members details on a website I'm making but I keep getting this error from the update transaction.
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND member.memberID='6'' at line 1"

I have tried different ways of coding it but the error is still the same.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include "../includes/connect.php"; 
?> 

<?php 
$memberID = $_POST['memberID']; //retrieve the memberID from the URL  
$firstName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstName']); 
$lastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastName']); 
$street = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['street']); 
$suburb = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['suburb']); 
$state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['state']); 
$postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['postcode']); 
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['country']); 
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']); 
$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mobile']); 
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']); 
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gender']); 
$newsletter = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['newsletter']); 

if ($firstName == "" || $lastName == "" || $postcode == "" || $country =="" || $email     == "" || $gender == "" || $newsletter == "") //check if all required fields have data
{ 
$_SESSION['error'] = 'All * fields are required.'; //if an error occurs intialise a session called 'error' with a msg 
header("location:memberupdate.php?memberID=" . $memberID); //redirect to memberupdate.php 
exit(); 
} 
elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //check if email is valid 
{ 
$_SESSION['error'] = 'Please enter a valid email address.'; //if an error occurs intialise a session called 'error' with a msg 
header("location:memberupdate.php?memberID=" . $memberID); //redirect to memberupdate.php 
exit(); 
} 
else 
{ 
$sql="START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE member SET firstName='$firstName',lastName='$lastName',phone='$phone',mobile='$mobile',email='$email',gender='$gender',newsletter='$newsletter' WHERE memberID='$memberID'; 
    UPDATE address SET street='$street',suburb='$suburb',state='$state',postcode='$postcode',country='$country' WHERE memberID='$memberID'; 
    COMMIT;"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)); //run the query 

$_SESSION['success'] = 'Member updated successfully.'; //if the member is updated successfully intialise a session called 'success' with a msg 
header("location:memberupdate.php?memberID=" . $memberID); //redirect to memberupdate.php 
} 
?>
```

please help!!

Comment: i think you need to use this `mysqli_multi_query`

Answer (score 0):

Is the memberID field in the table an int rather than a varchar? If so, then your code should say this (without the apostrophes around $memberID):

```
...WHERE memberID=$memberID"
```